# Firebase Android Wrong User displayed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It's showing something, but from the wrong user, not the signed-in user. In fact, it is the latest registred user. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getInstance().getReference("userInfos");

    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            UserInformation userInformation = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
            vorname.setText(userInformation.vorname);
            nachname.setText(userInformation.nachname);
            alter.setText(userInformation.alter);
            sprachen.setText(userInformation.sprachen);
            System.out.println("Prev: " + s);
        }
```

[Structure of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruZDT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the type of listener you're using is the ChildAdded one that will ge triggered when you add a new user (that's why you're getting the last added user) To get the current user data user, use a value event listener and pass the logged user id:

```
 String UID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
 DatabaseReference ref = database.getInstance().getReference("userInfos");

        ref.child(UID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         UserInformation userInformation = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
            vorname.setText(userInformation.vorname);
            nachname.setText(userInformation.nachname);
            alter.setText(userInformation.alter);
            sprachen.setText(userInformation.sprachen);
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {        
      }
    });
```

Comment: That is incorrect. The reason why the OP is printing out a wrong name is because the second argument of the `onChildAdded` method is actually the `previousChildName`. Please see my answer. Therefore in your answer, this line of code: `System.out.println("Prev: " + s);` will produce a compile error. `s` is undefined.

Comment: I see your point, and I've removed the line that would cause a compilation error. Still the problem the OP is facing is because in the UI they're setting the data that come from dataSnapshot not from the previous child, in fact they use the variable `s` only to show in the logs. Still, by removing the line of code you suggested the answer is correct, ebcause it retrieves the data from the current user as desired by the OP

Comment: By using the ChildAdded listener, when the other user is added to the users node, this listener will get trigered and that's why the OP was seeing the data from another user.

Comment: as you said addValueEventListener is the answer for me, but don't forget to readjust the security rules in Firebase console, if you are seeing info about another user while development it is fine, but in deployment it should not happen, The user can easily decompile the app and change the UID by another value and trigger a request on another user's behalf. Finally, if you only want to read the user's info once use addListenerForSingleValueEvent instead, or addValueEventListener and removeEventListener just after the first read. If you don't then the listener will be triggered each time

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
System.out.println("Prev: " + s);
```

The `s` variable holds a value of type String that is actually coming from the second argument of the overridden method `onChildAdded()`. According to the [offical documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener.html#onChildAdded(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot,%20java.lang.String)), the second argument can be also written as:

```
onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName)
```

That's why you are printing a wrong name. So the second argument is actually the name of the previous child.